# Someone received a text from my iphone. I don't even have the number the text was sent to

Tags: mobile

My son said two of his friends received a text from my phone, showing my phone number. I don't have these boys phone numbers in my phone or know their names. How did this happen?

Answer (score 3):

This is because much like [emails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing), text messages can be [spoofed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_spoofing) too. Basically what happened is someone generated a message and sent it to some sort of SMS generating and sending program that uses a fake phone number to some how send out real text messages. It just so turns out your number was used. You should keep a watch on this and see if it happens again. Until then there are some steps you can take to make sure you don't have a virus on your phone that's hiding them from you and that it really is a spam message.

- Install an anti virus application on your phone and run a scan
- Call the cell company and see if any texts where sent from your phone to those numbers(yes they keep records of that)

After these steps you should know whether or not you sent the text or someone spoofed your number and sent them. If it was the first, it might be time to talk to IT. If you were a spoofing victim, inform the phone company, and if it happens anymore get a new phone number.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the sender of the SMS message 'spoofed' the message, so that it appears to have been sent from your phone number.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_spoofing for more info on this subject.

Comment: To clarify, the texts probably came from the OP's son's phone with a spoofed number of the OP.